# Detect if any value is above zero and change it

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
[(True,False,True), (False,False,False), (False,False,True)]
```

If any element contains a True then they should all be true. So the above should become:

```
[(True,True,True), (False,False,False), (True,True,True)]
```

My below code attempts to do that but it simply converts all elements to True:

```
a = np.array([(True,False,True), (False,False,False), (False,True,False)], dtype='bool')
aint = a.astype('int')
print(aint)
aint[aint.sum() > 0] = (1,1,1)
print(aint.astype('bool'))
```

The output is:

```
[[1 0 1]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]]

[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `np.any`, which [tests whether any array element along a given axis evaluates to True](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html).

Here's a quick line of code that uses a list comprehension to get your intended result.

```
lst = [(True,False,True), (False,False,False), (False,False,True)]
result = [(np.any(x),) * len(x) for x in lst]

# result is [(True, True, True), (False, False, False), (True, True, True)]
```

Comment: To add to this, you can do `result = [[any(x)] * len(x) for x in lst]` if you prefer not to use numpy

Answer (score 0):

I'm no `numpy` wizard but this should return what you want.

```
import numpy as np

def switch(arr):
    if np.any(arr):
        return np.ones(*arr.shape).astype(bool)
    return arr.astype(bool)

np.apply_along_axis(switch, 1, a)

array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`ndarray.any` along `axis=1` and `np.tile` will get job done

```
np.tile(a.any(1)[:,None], a.shape[1])

array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `True`'s  based on the original array's second dimension and assign it to all rows that have a `True` in it.

```
>>> a
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])

>>> a[a.any(1)] = np.ones(a.shape[1], dtype=bool)
>>> a
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
>>>
```

---

Relies on [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).